# Configuring roleManager provider with MVC Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, role-manager

I always get an error when running my MVC Project since I put 
this code on my `web.config` file.

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="SM.MyRoleProvider"  />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

This is what my error looks like :

Configuration Error

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This method cannot be called during the
>   application's pre-start initialization phase.

Please can someone tell me whats going on ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must be go to in visual studio and go to path:
website tab -> ASP.NET Configuration ->security tab -> disabled role